# Inline CSS styles in React: how to implement a:hover?

Tags: reactjs

I quite like the [inline CSS pattern in React](https://speakerdeck.com/vjeux/react-css-in-js) and decided to use it.

However, you can't use the `:hover` and similar selectors. So what's the best way to implement highlight-on-hover while using inline CSS styles?

One suggestion from #reactjs is to have a `Clickable` component and use it like this:

```jsx
<Clickable>
    <Link />
</Clickable>
```

The `Clickable` has a `hovered` state and passes it as props to the Link. However, the `Clickable` (the way I implemented it) wraps the `Link` in a `div` so that it can set `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` to it. This makes things a bit complicated though (e.g. `span` wrapped in a `div` behaves differently than `span`).

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You're absolutely right - the only way to simulate :hover etc selectors with inline styles is to use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`. Regarding the exact implementation of that - it's entirely up to you. To look at your specific example, why not make the `<Clickable/>` wrapper a `span`?

Comment: i would suggest using external style sheets along with ExtractText Webpack plugin , this will help you on longer run if you ever wish to ServerRender otherwise you can try Radium  https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium

Comment: Currently [Styled Component](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) is best solution to simulate all possibilities of css/scss in react.

Comment: Well, the C in CSS stands for cascading.  When we go inline, we lose cascading features such as `:hover`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I'm in the same situation. Really like the pattern of keeping the styling in the components but the hover states seems like the last hurdle.

What I did was writing a mixin that you can add to your component that needs hover states.
This mixin will add a new `hovered` property to the state of your component. It will be set to `true` if the user hovers over the main DOM node of the component and sets it back to `false` if the users leaves the element.

Now in your component render function you can do something like:

```
<button style={m(
     this.styles.container,
     this.state.hovered && this.styles.hover,
)}>{this.props.children}</button>
```

Now each time the state of the `hovered` state changes the component will rerender.

I've also create a sandbox repo for this that I use to test some of these patterns myself. Check it out if you want to see an example of my implementation.

https://github.com/Sitebase/cssinjs/tree/feature-interaction-mixin

Comment: not a good solution for longer run,  Radium will be better choice or using an external stylesheet

Comment: @abhirathore2006 Radium works the same way and the question is specifically how to do this without using an external stylesheet

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use a vanilla spread operator?

Comment: What is an `m` per the above?

Answer (score 144):

I think onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave are the ways to go, but I don't see the need for an additional wrapper component.  Here is how I implemented it:

```
var Link = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {hover: false}
  },
  toggleHover: function(){
    this.setState({hover: !this.state.hover})
  },
  render: function() {
    var linkStyle;
    if (this.state.hover) {
      linkStyle = {backgroundColor: 'red'}
    } else {
      linkStyle = {backgroundColor: 'blue'}
    }
    return(
      <div>
        <a style={linkStyle} onMouseEnter={this.toggleHover} onMouseLeave={this.toggleHover}>Link</a>
      </div>
    )
}
```

You can then use the state of hover (true/false) to change the style of the link.

Comment: This would seem to cover `:hover` but not `:focus`

Comment: @AdamTuttle react has an `onFocus` event; so you could do the same thing for `:focus` as `:hover`, except instead of needing `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` you would only need `onFocus`

Comment: Be aware that this method forces execution on the main thread whereas typical CSS events are handled much more efficiently.

Answer (score 113):

Late to party but come with solution. You can use "&" to defines styles for hover nth Child etc:

```
day: {
    display: "flex",
    flex: "1",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "50px",
    height: "50px",
    transition: "all 0.2s",
    borderLeft: "solid 1px #cccccc",

    "&:hover": {
      background: "#efefef"
    },
    "&:last-child": {
      borderRight: "solid 1px #cccccc"
    }
},
```

Comment: Dude, take a look closer. This IS inline style.

Comment: This doesn't work with React. You need an extra library like styled-components.

Comment: It doesn't work with inline style, this example bring confusion. If it is really working, please provide a better example with full component.

Comment: Excellent! Works like a charm!

Comment: Would this not require a Sass dependency?

Comment: This did work for me, however I'm using the withStyles function from material ui to provided the 'classes' property to my component. Not sure if that has something to do with it.

Comment: This does not work purely on React, tested on https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-roentgen-yo57x

Comment: works perfect with  material ui's `makeStyles` hook. thanks

Comment: This Solution is ONLY for those using material UI.

Comment: @RishabhRathod it works fine with styled-components too.

Comment: Man this would be nice to have in vanilla React. React wants users to use the `style` prop to style components, but since you can't use any sort of media queries or selectors in the `style` prop by default it quickly becomes impossible to stick to it for styling. Very unfortunate.

Comment: This is a [JSS plugin](https://cssinjs.org/) answer. It won't work if you try to apply it to an element's css directly. It will work for libraries (like Material UI) that use JSS for their styling.

Comment: +1 for styled components. I had hoped this would work in plain react with no libraries: style={{ width: '34px', height: '29px', filter: 'grayscale(1)', '&:hover': { filter: 'unset' } }} The idea is from styled components. I guess I'll just use CSS with !important for that bit as not wanting to use Styled Components in this scenario.

Answer (score 29):

You can use Radium - it is an open source tool for inline styles with ReactJS. It adds exactly the selectors you need. Very popular, check it out - [Radium on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/radium)

Comment: I just came across this post, how would you implement Radium in the following situation?
`module.exports = React.createClass({ displayName: 'App',})`

Comment: @Rkhayat You can either wrap it as `module.exports = Radium(React.createClass({ displayName: 'App',}))` or assign the class to a value and add the `@Radium` decorator above it as the docs mention https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium#usage

Comment: there's also this great thing called CSS ;)

Answer (score 26):

Here's my solution using React Hooks. It combines the spread operator and the ternary operator.

style.js

```
export default {
  normal:{
    background: 'purple',
    color: '#ffffff'
  },
  hover: {
    background: 'red'
  }
}
```

Button.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import style from './style.js'

function Button(){

  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

  return(
    <button
      onMouseEnter={()=>{
        setHover(true);
      }}
      onMouseLeave={()=>{
        setHover(false);
      }}
      style={{
        ...style.normal,
        ...(hover ? style.hover : null)
      }}>

        MyButtonText

    </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: I love how creative folks get with these type of things, and you could probably make this even cleaner and more reusable using a custom hook like `const {onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave, styles } = useHoverStyle(style.hover)`

Having said that, it makes me sad we have to rely on such convoluted JS because of lacking inline style support for hover state 

Answer (score 20):

Heres is another option using CSS variables . This requires a css hover definition ahead of time so I guess its not pure inline, but is very little code and flexible.

css (setup a hover state) :

```
.p:hover:{
 color:var(--hover-color) !important,
 opacity:var(--hover-opacity)
}
```

react:

```
<p style={{'color':'red','--hover-color':'blue','--hover-opacity':0.5}}>
```

Comment: This is the best answer! clean, no dependencies, understandable, and most importantly, working! Thanks @yeahdixon

Comment: Definitely should be the accepted answer as @Shahriar already said.

Comment: This is by far the best answer since you can use it with server components

Answer (score 19):

Full CSS support is exactly the reason this huge amount of CSSinJS libraries, to do this efficiently, you need to generate actual CSS, not inline styles. Also inline styles are much slower in react in a bigger system. Disclaimer - I maintain [JSS](http://cssinjs.org).

Comment: what makes it slower?

Comment: @ICW Because JS is involved in it.

Answer (score 14):

I found a clean way to do this with a wrapper around `useState`, which I call `useHover`.
No additional libraries/frameworks needed.

```
const App = () => {

    const hover = useHover({backgroundColor: "LightBlue"})

    return <p {...hover}>Hover me!</p>
}
```

Code for the wrapper:

```
function useHover(styleOnHover: CSSProperties, styleOnNotHover: CSSProperties = {})
{
    const [style, setStyle] = React.useState(styleOnNotHover);

    const onMouseEnter = () => setStyle(styleOnHover)
    const onMouseLeave = () => setStyle(styleOnNotHover)

    return {style, onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave}
}
```

Note that `useHover` has an optional second parameter for a style when the component is not hovered.

Try it out [here](https://codepen.io/3dgrabber/pen/xxrVvrR?editors=0010)

Answer (score 12):

Made [Style It](https://github.com/buildbreakdo/style-it) -- in part -- because of this reason (others being disagreements with implementation of other libs / syntax and inline stylings lack of support for prefixing property values). Believe we should be able to simply write CSS in JavaScript and have fully self contained components HTML-CSS-JS. With ES5 / ES6 template strings we now can and it can be pretty too! :)

`npm install style-it --save`

**Functional Syntax** ([JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y2pnqh9e/27/))

```js
import React from 'react';
import Style from 'style-it';

class Intro extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return Style.it(`
      .intro:hover {
        color: red;
      }
    `,
      <p className="intro">CSS-in-JS made simple -- just Style It.</p>
    );
  }
}

export default Intro;
```

**JSX Syntax** ([JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y2pnqh9e/31/))

```js
import React from 'react';
import Style from 'style-it';

class Intro extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Style>
      {`
        .intro:hover {
          color: red;
        }
      `}

        <p className="intro">CSS-in-JS made simple -- just Style It.</p>
      </Style>
    );
  }
}

export default Intro;
```

Comment: I noticed on the JSX Syntax example, the JSFiddle link has the correct code, but the example shown here is missing the closing parenthesis after the closing Style tag and the indentation is off probably because of the missing parenthesis.

Comment: This is great, used so many wet solutions until I found this

Answer (score 9):

```
onMouseEnter={(e) => {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#e13570';
    e.target.style.border = '2px solid rgb(31, 0, 69)';
    e.target.style.boxShadow = '-2px 0px 7px 2px #e13570';
}}
onMouseLeave={(e) => {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(31, 0, 69)';
    e.target.style.border = '2px solid #593676';
    e.target.style.boxShadow = '-2px 0px 7px 2px #e13570';
}}
```

Set default properties in the style or class then call onMouseLeave() and onMouseEnter() to create a hover functionality.

Comment: The simplest option of all the ones here, don't use any dependency and works fine. Thanks!

Comment: For typescript cast first using `const target = e.target as HTMLElement;`

Comment: `e.currentTarget` works better for typescript.

Answer (score 8):

Adding on to [Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33000431/4933257%20%22Jonathan's%20answer), here are the events to cover the focus and active states, and a using `onMouseOver` instead of `onMouseEnter` since the latter will not bubble if you have any child elements within the target the event is being applied to.

```
var Link = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {hover: false, active: false, focus: false}
  },

  toggleHover: function(){
    this.setState({hover: !this.state.hover})
  },

  toggleActive: function(){
    this.setState({active: !this.state.active})
  },

  toggleFocus: function(){
    this.setState({focus: !this.state.focus})
  },

  render: function() {
    var linkStyle;
    if (this.state.hover) {
      linkStyle = {backgroundColor: 'red'}
    } else if (this.state.active) {
      linkStyle = {backgroundColor: 'blue'}
    } else if (this.state.focus) {
      linkStyle = {backgroundColor: 'purple'}
    } 

    return(
      <div>
        <a style={linkStyle} 
          onMouseOver={this.toggleHover} 
          onMouseOut={this.toggleHover} 
          onMouseUp={this.toggleActive} 
          onMouseDown={this.toggleActive} 
          onFocus={this.toggleFocus}> 
          Link 
        </a>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: What about tab interaction for accessibility? I think this is just a workaround.

Answer (score 7):

In regards to [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#supported-css) and [react-router v4](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) you can do this:

```
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'

const Link = styled(NavLink)`     
  background: blue;

  &:hover {
    color: white;
  }
`

...
<Clickable><Link to="/somewhere">somewhere</Link></Clickable>
```

Answer (score 7):

This can be a nice hack for having inline style inside a react component (and also using :hover CSS function):

```
...

<style>
  {`.galleryThumbnail.selected:hover{outline:2px solid #00c6af}`}
</style>

...
```

Comment: did the trick for me, thank you

Answer (score 6):

Checkout [Typestyle](http://typestyle.io/#/core) if you are using React with Typescript.

Below is a sample code for :hover

```
import {style} from "typestyle";

/** convert a style object to a CSS class name */
const niceColors = style({
  transition: 'color .2s',
  color: 'blue',
  $nest: {
    '&:hover': {
      color: 'red'
    }
  }
});

<h1 className={niceColors}>Hello world</h1>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just create an `abstract` hovering class e.g. for the color.

```
.hoverClassColor:hover {
  color:var(--hover-color) !important;
}
```

Then for all Elements you wanna changes the color to `red` on hovering:

```
render() {
  return <a className={'hoverClassColor'} style={{'--hover-color':'red'}}>Test</a>
}
```

For me its like inline, cause the classes are abstract and can be reused for all of your elements you wanna implement a color hovering.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, it is the only true inline solution I've found so far. the others keep using external libraries or state to switch classes

Answer (score 5):

The simple way is using ternary operator

```
var Link = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {hover: false}
  },
  toggleHover: function(){
    this.setState({hover: !this.state.hover})
  },
  render: function() {
    var linkStyle;
    if (this.state.hover) {
      linkStyle = {backgroundColor: 'red'}
    } else {
      linkStyle = {backgroundColor: 'blue'}
    }
    return(
      <div>
        <a style={this.state.hover ? {"backgroundColor": 'red'}: {"backgroundColor": 'blue'}} onMouseEnter={this.toggleHover} onMouseLeave={this.toggleHover}>Link</a>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way 2022:
useRef + inline onMouseOver/onMouseOut

example:

```
 var bottomAtag = useRef(null)
```

> ...then inside return (

```
 <a ref={bottomAtag} onMouseOver={() => bottomAtag.current.style.color='#0F0'} ...></a>
```

Comment: I like this solution.  Relatively simple.  Using your example, I declared bottomAtag as a const instead of a var though and added an onMouseLeave function to return it to its previous styling after leaving.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [css modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) as an alternative, and additionally [react-css-modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules) for class name mapping.

That way you can import your styles as follows and use normal css scoped locally to your components:

```
import React from 'react';
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';
import styles from './table.css';

class Table extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return <div styleName='table'>
            <div styleName='row'>
                <div styleName='cell'>A0</div>
                <div styleName='cell'>B0</div>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}

export default CSSModules(Table, styles);
```

Here is a [webpack css modules example](https://github.com/css-modules/webpack-demo)

Comment: FYI: If you are using Meteor check out this package: https://github.com/nathantreid/meteor-css-modules. I am using it myself having great success so far.

Comment: This is a great way to style react components, but doesn't quite give you all the control of inline styles. For example, you cannot change `:hover` styles at runtime like you can with Radium or another `onMouseOver` based solution

Answer (score 4):

onMouseOver and onMouseLeave with setState at first seemed like a bit of overhead to me - but as this is how react works, it seems the easiest and cleanest solution to me.

rendering a theming css serverside for example, is also a good solution and keeps the react components more clean.

if you dont have to append dynamic styles to elements ( for example for a theming ) you should not use inline styles at all but use css classes instead.

this is a traditional html/css rule to keep html / JSX clean and simple.

Answer (score 3):

This is a universal wrapper for hover written in typescript. The component will apply style passed via props 'hoverStyle' on hover event.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Hover: React.FC<{
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  hoverStyle: React.CSSProperties;
}> = ({ style = {}, hoverStyle, children }) => {
  const [isHovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
  const calculatedStyle = { ...style, ...(isHovered ? hoverStyle : {}) };
  return (
    <div
      style={calculatedStyle}
      onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(false)}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily achived with [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#makestyles-withstyles-styled) `makeStyles` invocation:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

makeStyles({
  root: {
    /* … */
    '&:hover': { /* … */ }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this trick, a mix between inline-style and css:

```
//inline-style:
const button = {
  fontSize: "2em",
};
return (
  <div style={button} data-hover="button">
    <style>{`[data-hover="button"]:hover {
        font-size: 2.1em !important;
    }`}</style>
    {this.props.text}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66807634/3862142), but I do not use material-ui or makeStyles. I added the hover as a condition in my css in a style object:

```
const styles = {
  hoverStyle: {
    color: 'grey',
    '&:hover': { color: 'blue !important' },
  }
};

var NavBar = (props) => {
  const menuOptions = ['home', 'blog', 'projects', 'about'];

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {menuOptions.map((page) => <div style={styles.hoverStyle} key={page}>{page}</div> )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This worked for me.

Comment: It outputs: `&: hover: [object Object];`

Comment: probably works only if you have sass integrated in the project too otherwise is not (I just tested and the hover declaration is simply discarded)

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 1):

With a using of the hooks:

```
const useFade = () => {
  const [ fade, setFade ] = useState(false);

  const onMouseEnter = () => {
    setFade(true);
  };

  const onMouseLeave = () => {
    setFade(false);
  };

  const fadeStyle = !fade ? {
    opacity: 1, transition: 'all .2s ease-in-out',
  } : {
    opacity: .5, transition: 'all .2s ease-in-out',
  };

  return { fadeStyle, onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave };
};

const ListItem = ({ style }) => {
  const { fadeStyle, ...fadeProps } = useFade();

  return (
    <Paper
      style={{...fadeStyle, ...style}}
      {...fadeProps}
    >
      {...}
    </Paper>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Hoverable hoverStyle={styles.linkHover}>
  <a href="https://example.com" style={styles.link}>
    Go
  </a>
</Hoverable>
```

Where Hoverable is defined as:

```
function Hoverable(props) {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

  const child = Children.only(props.children);

  const onHoverChange = useCallback(
    e => {
      const name = e.type === "mouseenter" ? "onMouseEnter" : "onMouseLeave";
      setHover(!hover);
      if (child.props[name]) {
        child.props[name](e);
      }
    },
    [setHover, hover, child]
  );

  return React.cloneElement(child, {
    onMouseEnter: onHoverChange,
    onMouseLeave: onHoverChange,
    style: Object.assign({}, child.props.style, hover ? props.hoverStyle : {})
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it with hooks in functional components. With `onMouseEnter/Leave`, im setting the color as state directly and consume it in the style prop of element (instead of setting hover state and using ternaries to change the state as shown in previous answers).

```js
function App() {
  const [col, setCol] = React.useState('white');

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        style={{background: `${col}`}}
        onMouseEnter={() => setCol("red")}
        onMouseLeave={() => setCol("white")}
      >
        Red
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-3vo65ZXn5pfsCfGM5H55X+SmwJHBlyNHPwRmWAPgJnM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-qVsF1ftL3vUq8RFOLwPnKimXOLo72xguDliIxeffHRc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a pretty hack-ish solution for this in one of my recent applications that works for my purposes, and I find it quicker than writing custom hover settings functions in vanilla js (though, I recognize, maybe not a best practice in most environments..) So, in case you're still interested, here goes.

I create a parent element just for the sake of holding the inline javascript styles, then a child with a className or id that my css stylesheet will latch onto and write the hover style in my dedicated css file. This works because the more granular child element receives the inline js styles via inheritance, but has its hover styles overridden by the css file.

So basically, my actual css file exists for the sole purpose of holding hover effects, nothing else. This makes it pretty concise and easy to manage, and allows me to do the heavy-lifting in my in-line React component styles.

Here's an example:

```js
const styles = {
  container: {
    height: '3em',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    borderBottom: '1px solid gainsboro',
  },
  parent: {
    display: 'flex',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    color: 'darkgrey',
  },
  child: {
    width: '6em',
    textAlign: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    lineHeight: '3em',
  },
};

var NavBar = (props) => {
  const menuOptions = ['home', 'blog', 'projects', 'about'];

  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <div style={styles.parent}>
        {menuOptions.map((page) => <div className={'navBarOption'} style={styles.child} key={page}>{page}</div> )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(
  <NavBar/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
.navBarOption:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Notice that the "child" inline style does not have a "color" property set. If it did, this would not work because the inline style would take precedence over my stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the answer, but its the trick i use to simulate the CSS :hover effect with colours and images inline.

```
`This works best with an image`

class TestHover extends React.PureComponent {
render() {
const landingImage = {     
"backgroundImage": "url(https://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/09/01/18/2BE1E88B00000578-3218613-image-m-5_1441127035222.jpg)",
"BackgroundColor": "Red", `this can be any color`
"minHeight": "100%",
"backgroundAttachment": "fixed",
"backgroundPosition": "center",
"backgroundRepeat": "no-repeat",
"backgroundSize": "cover", 
"opacity": "0.8", `the hove trick is here in the opcaity slightly see through gives the effect when the background color changes`
    }

  return (
    <aside className="menu">
        <div className="menu-item">
          <div style={landingImage}>SOME TEXT</div>
        </div>
    </aside>
      ); 
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <TestHover />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
top: 2.70em;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
}

.menu-item {
cursor: pointer;
height: 100%;
font-size: 2em;
line-height: 1.3em;
color: #000;
font-family: "Poppins";
font-style: italic;
font-weight: 800;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
}
```

> Before hover

```
.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
color: white;
background-color: #001b37;
}
```

> On hover

```
.menu-item:nth-child(1):hover {
color: green;
background-color: white;
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/roryfn/pen/dxyYqj?editors=0011

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same situation recently. Here's my pretty simple solution with a custom hook that returns if element is hovered or not.

```
export const useOnHover = (ref: React.RefObject) => {
    const [hovered, setHovered] = React.useState(false);

    const mouseEntered = React.useCallback(() => {
        setHovered(true);
    }, [ref.current]);

    const mouseLeft = React.useCallback(() => {
        setHovered(false);
    }, [ref.current]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!ref.current) return;

        ref.current.addEventListener("mouseenter", mouseEntered);
        ref.current.addEventListener("mouseleave", mouseLeft);

        return () => {
            if (!ref.current) return;
            ref.current.removeEventListener("mouseenter", mouseEntered);
            ref.current.removeEventListener("mouseleave", mouseLeft);
        };
    }, [ref.current]);

    return hovered;
};
```

Now you can use it on any element like so:

```js
const Button = (props) => {
    const buttonRef = React.useRef(null);

    const buttonHovered = useOnHover(buttonRef);
    return (
        <div
            ref={buttonRef}
            style={{
                //your styles
                backgroundColor: "red",
                filter: buttonHovered ? "saturate(100%)" : "saturate(50%)",
            }}
        >
            {props.title}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Even better: you can utilize the function props `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` instead of attaching listeners

Answer (score 0):

This solution does use stylesheets.  However, If your application uses an index.css - i.e. has a stylesheet that gets imported into your top-level component, you could just write the following code in there

```
.hoverEffect:hover {
 //add some hover styles
}
```

Then in your React component, just add the className "hoverEffect" to apply the hover effect "inline".

If the hover state is being passed down as a prop, and you only want it to be applied to the child component, remove the :hover in your index.css, and do this instead.

```
function Link(props) {
  return (
    <a className={props.isHovered ? "hoverEffect" : ""}>Hover me<a/>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly use  tag in your component like this:

```
<Wrapper>
  <style>
   .custom-class{
       // CSS here
   }
   .custom-class:hover{
     //query selector
   }
  </style>
  <div className="custom-class"></div>
</Wrapper>
```