# Dispatch from action to reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm having a bit of struggle to get a few things with Redux. I got the following code and what I'm trying to do is to push things to the reducer, can I dispatch here and how do I do that? Im used to Vue and Vuex and there I can use `commit()` (as seen in the example below)

```
export function subscribeToResponsiveEvents() {
  _.forOwn(breakpoints, (mediaQuery, key) => {
    const mql = window.matchMedia(mediaQuery)

    const callback = ({ matches }) => {
      // how I do it in Vue
      // commit('set_responsive_data', { path: ['breakpoints', key], value: matches })

      // I would like to dispatch this to the reducer
    }

    mql.addListener(callback)
    callback(mql)
  })

  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', e => {
    // how I do it in Vue
    // commit('set_responsive_data', { path: 'screenOrientation', value: window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth ? 'landscape' : 'portrait' })

    // I would like to dispatch this to the reducer
  })
}
```

I know I can do like this, but as I got a loop here and don't want to return, just call the reducer to change the state I'm a bit confused on how.

```
export function somefunction() {
  return { type: SET_RESPONSIVE_DATA, payload }
}
```

Comment: To the close vote, what more need clearicifaction, I'm very clear with that "I'm trying to push things to the reducer", also there are comments in the code? So please leave a comment and be more specific.

Comment: So in this case you can either import a store you passed to redux and call `dispatch` directly on it or move this logic to a component's lifecycle method `componendDidMount` or `useEffect` hook (preferred way). By reading the code it looks like you're trying to save device's screen parameters to the store, is there are a particular reason for this? Can't you just stick to css? If you only need it for the responsiveness I'd think again about storing it in redux

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35073669/window-resize-react-redux

Comment: @mikheevm How does it work with the store and instances? How would I import a store? I already got `const store = configureStore()` in index.js where I pass it to react-redux provider (hence my question about instances). I got a `configureStore.js` with some basic stuff that goes in there (`createStore`). This will be used all over the application so I can't put in a component. Regarding the css, at large scale projects I don't want some parts to render if they are not in the right media query.

Comment: `export const store = configureStore()`
`import { store } from './store'`
`store.dispatch({ type: SET_RESPONSIVE_DATA, payload })`

Comment: @mikheevm two questions. If I `export const store = ...` in my index.js, can that const be used later down in the file or is this just exporting it? Also would it be good practise to export "things" just like that, this pattern seems a little bit of to me?

Comment: Yes it can be used as it will still point to the same instance. Importing a store and using it outside of the components is not an anti-pattern, it's just not the recommended way of doing things: https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#can-or-should-i-create-multiple-stores-can-i-import-my-store-directly-and-use-it-in-components-myself
This is why I advise you to place it inside the component. You can place it, for example, in your app component's `componentDidMount` or `useEffect` and then get the data from the store using `connect` from `react-redux` in another components

Comment: @mikheevm My store is in the index.js. If I place it in App.js, should I import there store there as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200154/discussion-between-mikheevm-and-dejan-s).