# How to use API returned image for background image in media query?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, media-queries

I have this in my style.scss:

```
.myComponent {

    &__pic {

        // some other styles

        @media (max-width: 767px),
          (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
          (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
          background-image: url({this needs to come from API});
        }

    }

}
```

I know how to do if it's just the default background image, like so:

```
<div className="col-md-8">
    <div className="myComponent__pic" style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${someObject.someImage})`
    }} />
</div>
```

But how do I specify the `@media` style outside the stylesheet so that I can give it the image (`someObject.someImage2x`) coming from the API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inline CSS styles in React: how to implement media queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405444/inline-css-styles-in-react-how-to-implement-media-queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use CSS variables as a workaround.

```js
let imageQuery = {
  --backgroundImage-2x: `url(${someObject.someImage2x})`,
  --backgroundImage-1x: `url(${someObject.someImage1x})`
}

<div className="col-md-8">
    <div className="myComponent__pic" style={imageQuery} />
</div>
```

```css
.myComponent {

    &__pic {
        --backgroundImage-2x: "";
        --backgroundImage-1x: "";
        // some other styles
        
        background-image: var(--backgroundImage-1x);
        
        @media (max-width: 767px),
          (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
          (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
          background-image: var(--backgroundImage-2x);
        }

    }

}
```