# how to change the color of a button when a mouse moves over it using React?

Tags: css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

With the next command:

```
function createCustomInsertButton (onClick) {
  return (
    <button style={ { color: 'yellow', padding: '5px', paddingBottom : '6px', border: '1px', background:'red' } } onClick={ onClick }>Add New User</button>
  );
}
```

I created a red button but every time my mouse goes over it its color stays red. Can this be changed inside the  cmd? I mean, if my mouse goes over the button, could its color be changed to light red? the constraint is, I can only use react related stuff (no external CSS files)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365233/inline-css-styles-in-react-how-to-implement-ahover

Comment: related, I believe yes... easy... I don't think so

Comment: what do you mean by "inside the cmd"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this without using stateful component with pure React unless you use an external *css-in-js* library like [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components).

Anyway, the idea is: you can keep the `background` as a state in the button component and attach `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` listeners to change the `state` accordingly. Then you can rely on React to do the rest of the dirty re-rerendering work for you.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/PZB1ZxMBy

However, using *styled-components* for this kind of thing is more performant as it does not use inline CSS. This approach is also more clear and concise. So, if you have an option of using external libraries like *styled-components*, be sure to check it out.

Here's a little demo for *styled-components*: https://codesandbox.io/s/9rZkQ0BpJ