# React jsx conditional styling of <input/> component

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I am conditionally styling my `<input/>` (standard HTML) component. I am passing inline JSX style as a `style` prop:

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          paddingLeft: "8px",
          paddingTop: "6px",
          paddingBottom: "6px",

          border: this.state.error
            ? "2px solid red"
            : this.state.value
            ? "2px solid #2684ff"
            : "2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 80%)",
          outline: "0px",

          "&:hover": {
            border: "2px solid green"
          }
        }}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        onChange={this.handleInput}
        onFocus={this.checkErrors}
        value={this.state.value}
        onBlur={this.sendData}
      />

      {this.state.error ? (
        <div className="errorMsg"> {this.props.errorMsg} </div>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}
```

My conditional styles work, and `<input/>` border colour changes based on `this.state.error` and `this.state.value`, however I can't get `'&:hover'` style to work. I have checked my .css and there is nothing overriding the style passed as props.

I have tried another approach, where I conditionally set `className` for my `<input/>` and define style in external `.css` file. It works and I can change border colour with:

```
    input[type="text"]:hover {
      border: 2px solid pink;
    }
```

However, I would like to make this work in inline JSX. Why does my style for `'&:hover': { ... }` not work?

Comment: you cannot use `&:hover` pseudo classes in style

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles. You could however use mouseover to add styles.

Comment: You could find the answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/28369384/5789381

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "&" operator mean the current selector in preprocessing language like sass:

```
input {
  &:hover {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

Will compile to:

```
input:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

But you will have to use [sass](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/) or [styled component](https://styled-components.com/) to use that sync tax.

Comment: Thanks! I was puzzled why the same styling worked for my other component based on `react-select`. I discovered that `react-select` uses `@emotion/core` to handle the styling. Since I already used `@emotion/core` in my other component, I solved the issue by 1. `import { jsx } from @emotion/core`, 2. adding jsx pragma `/** @jsx jsx */` and 3. changing the prop name from `style` to `css`.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo css selectors don't work in inline style.btw I would not recommend any of the js solution in the comments above .you need a more a robust css solution to handle all kind of pseudo selectors.
Your options are:

1. Use css in js solution like styled-components.https://styled-components.com/
2. Use regular css or scss and condionaly switch classNames.You 
   can utilize classnames library for easier experience.https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames
3. Render style tag above your input and put your input styles there.quite bad practice and ugly.