# How to change icon color on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change the color of a material icon inside `IconButton` material component (an action that should trigger color change - hover over `IconButton`).

How this could be done? Adding class to the icon directly works only if hover over icon itself and not over `IconButton`.

My code:

```
<IconButton className="add-icon-btn" onClick={toggleNominationForm}>
  {!showForm ? <AddBoxIcon /> : <IndeterminateCheckBoxIcon /> }
</IconButton>
```

[image]

Comment: A working stackblitz demo would really help in understanding your query.

Comment: I don't know why, but I can't create a workable app there - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gwnrwh

Comment: Just check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57439691/7060441) You don't need to use the spread part if you don't want to and use it simply like `<AddBoxIcon style={{backgroundColor: hover ? "blue" : "yellow"}} />`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you have a full example, I hope this solves your problem:

```
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles'
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton'
import AddBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddBox'
import IndeterminateCheckBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/IndeterminateCheckBox'

export default () => {

    const [showForm, setShowForm] = React.useState(false)
    const classes = useClasses()

    return (
        <IconButton
            classes={{
                root: classes.iconContainer
            }}
        >
            {!showForm
                ? <AddBoxIcon className={classes.icon}/>
                : <IndeterminateCheckBoxIcon className={classes.icon}/>
            }
        </IconButton>
    )
}

const useClasses = makeStyles(theme => ({
    iconContainer: {
        "&:hover $icon": {
            color: 'red',
        }
    },
    icon: {
        color: 'blue',
    },
}))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use following property

```js
sx={{ "&:hover": { color: "blue" } }}
```

```
<IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="show 17 new notifications"
              color="inherit"
              sx={{ "&:hover": { color: "blue" } }}
            >
              <Badge badgeContent={17} color="primary">
                <LayersIcon />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
```

Comment: I recommend adding a transition as well.  `transition: "color"`

Answer (score -2):

You need a `hover` state probably. So, you can use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` for the outer icon and then set the style by using this condition for the inner icon. This logic is borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57439691/7060441). So, I'm setting my answer as CW.

```
<IconButton
  onMouseEnter={() => {
    setHover(true);
  }}
  onMouseLeave={() => {
    setHover(false);
  }}
  className="add-icon-btn"
  onClick={toggleNominationForm}
>
  {!showForm ? (
    <AddBoxIcon style={{ backgroundColor: hover ? "blue" : "yellow" }} />
  ) : (
    <IndeterminateCheckBoxIcon />
  )}
</IconButton>
```

Comment: When using Material-UI it is preferred to use the built-in methods for styling e.g. "makeStyles"

Answer (score -2):

Try adding the following CSS -

```
.IconButton:hover .Iconclass {
  background-color: /*desired color*/;
}
```

Comment: When using Material-UI it is preferred to use the built-in methods for styling e.g. "makeStyles"