# how to apply hover in Inline styles

Tags: reactjs

```
       <div
            style={{
              height: '20px',
              width: '20px',
              background: 'url(add.svg)'
            }}
          ></div>
```

I have a div and i want to apply add.svg icon when its not hovered and when div is hovered i want to apply remove.svg icon.
How can i apply hover in inline styles?

```
           <div
            style={{
              height: '20px',
              width: '20px',
              background: 'url(add.svg)',
              ':hover': { background: 'url(remove.svg)', },
            }}
          ></div>
```

I tried  `':hover': { background: 'url(remove.svg)', }` in inline styles but not working.

Comment: Duplicate of [Inline CSS styles in React: how to implement a:hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365233/inline-css-styles-in-react-how-to-implement-ahover)

Comment: yes i have already read that question but none of the answers used ':hover' in inline styles as i want.

Comment: Is it a functional component or a class component?

Comment: Its Class based Component.

Comment: They don't user :hover in inline styles because it's not possible to use :hover in inline styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it with CSS only, but you can do it with JavaScript (assuming you are using a class based component), it is not that elegent but if there is a need this is how you can do it

```
<div
    onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({ hovering: true })}
    onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ hovering: false })}
    style={{ background: this.state.hovering ? "url(remove.svg)" : "url(add.svg)" }}
    style={{
        height: '20px',
        width: '20px',
        background: 'url(add.svg)'
    }}
></div>
```

This will change the background style based on the mouse hover state on the item.

Answer (score 2):

:pseudo-selectors are not working as inline styles. If you want to use it this way, maybe you can have a look at Tailwindcss.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pseudo-class-variants/#app

Answer (score 1):

> yes i have already read that question but none of the answers used ':hover' in inline styles as i want.

There's no way, means no way. We can't apply inline rule for `:pseudo` element.

However, some library functionality provides us to simulate `:hover` behavior for eg. look into the styled component. It does not mean that you're applying inline rule for `:hover`.

Furthermore, I don't understand why developers don't use class on such cases? I see a lot of answers tricking to the behavior whilst we can simply implement just with the class.

Comment: yes i mostly use classes but this code is already written by someone in a project i just need to change icons on hover. i have to replace their styles if i use classes.