# How to use pseudo class inside style attribute in React

Tags: css, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1
        style={{
          '&::hover': {
            color: 'white'
          },
          color: 'red'
        }}
      >Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This hover does not work, but I wanted to be able to do it within the component's style, without a css file, class or objects.

Even if this method is not valid, there is some validity without using the components mentioned above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inline CSS styles in React: how to implement a:hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365233/inline-css-styles-in-react-how-to-implement-ahover)

Comment: I need it to be a solution within the component's own style, the solutions I saw were using variables

Answer (score 0):

The React JSX `style` attribute lets you provide an object of inline styles, but inline styles cannot include selectors like the pseudo-class `:hover`. Inline styles can only include properties. If you want to make inline styles more powerful, there are several methods of CSS-In-JS libraries that make this possible. Solutions I've tried include [Emotion](https://emotion.sh) (which I like a lot) and [`styled-components`](https://styled-components.com) (would not recommend).

Another possible option is [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com), which is a different kind of library that has a similar feel to what you want. I would personally recommend Tailwind as a go-to for this kind of thing.

Here's how you could do what you're looking for with Tailwind:

```html
<h1 className="color-red hover:color-white">Hello React.</h1>
```

Again, you can't do this with just inline style attributes.